# Storing and querying nested data in HBase

Tags: json, hbase

I am currently examining a way to store some data in HBase.

My data looks like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id":1,
            "interests": [
                {"name":"Soccer", "type":"sports", "level":"great"},
                {"name":"Swimming", "type":"sports", "lengths": [100,25,40]}
            ]
        }
    {...},{...}]
}
```

Later, I would like to access the names of interests of a row. Is there any way of creating some kind of array-columns? Like `family:interests[]`?

I realize it might be easier to store these data in `family:interests` and the JSON-Format they come in, but how will I address them later on? Which environment would you advise me to use for that?

This is just a conceptual question I couldn't find an answer to after skimming the literature... I am happy for any hint!